# Check if file name is unique, add integer if not and keep extension

Tags: php, string

I am trying to write a piece of code that checks if my filename is unique and if it is not return the file name with an integer appended to it.
So basically, if in my database i already have a record with "airco.jpg" in it.

Now if i run the function with "airco.jpg" as input, i want it to return
"airco_1.jpg". The next one would be "airco_2.jpg", etc...

This is the code I have so far, it returns "airco.jpg_1" because of the file extension. I know how to cut it off, but i am not sure how to add it again...

```
function return_unique_filename($filename) {
    //Remove the extension
    //$filename = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    $CI = get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('vacancy/vacancies_model');

    if (!$CI->vacancies_model->doesFilenameExist($filename)) {
        return $filename;
    }

    $counter = 1;
    while ($CI->vacancies_model->doesFilenameExist($filename . "_" . $counter)) {
        $counter++;
    }

    return $filename . "_" . $counter;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this be easier if you did this with your database and having the filename recorded? or in conjunction with what you're trying to do now.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner how do you mean exactly? The file name is stored in the database, but it contains extensions aswell .jpg , .jpeg, .png, ...

Comment: in all cases, put an `UNIQUE contraint` on the column `filename` in your SQL schema, it will block in any case the creation of a row whose filename has already been recorded.

Comment: you can use LIKE if using MySQL and not bother with extensions

Comment: If you are intent on using php there is an [array count values function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) which returns an array with the counts of all values and if the count is greater than 1 it isn't unique.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner would this still work if a filename contains "airco.jpg.jpg" for example? how do i use the like?

Comment: Using `WHERE
    column LIKE '%string';` - here's a reference link http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like - or `'string%';` depending on the filtering criteria. @Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the filename part commented out, you just need to tweak it to get the extension.

```
$file = "a.jpg";
$filename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: Thank you! i was not aware of the PATHINFO_EXTENSION , exactly what I needed

Comment: When a function has constants like this there is always (or at least most of the times) more than one constant to choose from. Just look up the function in the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php